# SwiftUI List - Conditional items break animations

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, transition, swiftui-list

I am having a rather interesting issue with SwiftUI at the moment. I have a List containing multiple items, including a DatePicker (which is not the cause, it affects all other views I have tried). Conditionally showing and hiding the DatePicker (with `if` and an EmptyView) results in the following animation:

https://thumbs.gfycat.com/PoshPertinentBettong-mobile.mp4 (I tried to embed the gif, but it wouldn't let me. Feel free to fix this up if possible) :)

(Note how the DatePicker clips out of the list item on the bottom in both animation directions. Other elements behave the same, but are less noticeable due to their height)

I can disable animations altogether, but do not want to. I have attempted to fix this issue with various `.transition`, `.animation`, etc modifiers, to no avail.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: I could reproduce the issue: https://github.com/ralfebert/SwiftUIPlayground/blob/master/SwiftUIPlayground/Views/ConditionalDatePickerView.swift . Seems like a SwiftUI bug to me. btw, how did you get the picker to display directly without another table row that expands/collapses in a List/Form?

Comment: Would you show demo code for this effect?

Comment: @Asperi It's basically what Ralf Ebert has provided.

Comment: @RalfEbert My date picker is actually a wrapped `UIDatePicker` with `countDownTimer` mode active. I am not sure whether that is what you were asking. Also, I think not providing a label shows it by default, but not 100% sure about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping during the animation when items are expanded/collapsed seems to be a bug in SwiftUI.

For iOS 13.4, you can see it happening even in the official Apple sample projects from the SwiftUI tutorials [WorkingWithUIControls](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/working-with-ui-controls) in the profile screen:

[image]